# Unable to create a file from its absolute address

Tags: java, file

I am trying to create a *config.properties* file in Java in order to store database details. The way I am trying to do this is by creating a *config.properties* file:

```
public ConfigurationFile() {
    File configFile = getConfigFile();
    System.out.println("Path is \n" + configFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
    System.out.println();
    if (!configFile.exists()) {
        try {
            configFile.createNewFile();
            createConfigFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

However, the program fails when it attempts to run the createNewFile() method:

```
Java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
at me.pabloestrada.beargameconfiguration.ConfigurationFile.<init>(ConfigurationFile.java:43)
```

I think the reason this is happening is because of an invalid address. I get the File object from these:

```
private File getConfigFile() {
    System.out.println("The execution path is \n" + getPath());
    System.out.println();
    return new File(getPath());
}

private String getPath() {
    return getExecutionPath() + "config.properties";
}
```

I debugged and getPath() returns the following address:

```
The execution path is 
Users/myuser/....../bearwar/target/config.properties
```

Which is correct. However, when I run configFile.getAbsolutePath(), the address seems to be incorrect:

```
Path is 
/Users/myuser/Users/myuser/......./bearwar/target/config.properties
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error in the absolute path of the file?

Comment: The path that you’re composing is _not_ an absolute path: it is not rooted, so it’s a relative path.  Relative paths are evaluated relative to the current working directory.  To make it an absolute path, it would need a leading `/`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel the one given by getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: The one beginning with `Users/`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel could you post that as an answer. That fixed it!

Comment: Did you make sure, that all the directories are available with mkdirs()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path that you’re composing (the one beginning with `Users/`) is *not* an absolute path: it is not rooted, so it’s a relative path. Relative paths are evaluated relative to the current working directory.

To make it an absolute path, it would need a leading `/`.